# Showing MVC URL Path through Controller/Action/RouteValues combination

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, extension-methods

I had a doubt which is the following:

When I use the following code:

```
@(Html.ActionLink("Click Me", "ACTION", new {QueryName = ViewBag.QueryName}))
```

I will get an HTML output like this:
**<a href="http://localhost/ControllerName/ACTION?QueryName=098"> Click Me </a>**

Ok, but what if I want to have the following as an HTML output?

**<span > I want just the "href" part of the action link http://localhost/ControllerName/ACTION?QueryName=098 , without the "a" tag </span>**

Do I have to write an extension for it or do I have some preexistent provision to do it?

I hope I was clear enough.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

So far I wrote an extension, which is clearly not the best way to do it, as you can see below, but I needed it:

```
public static class ActionURLPathExtension
{
    public static MvcHtmlString ActionURLPath(this HtmlHelper helper ,  string ActionName, string ControllerName, object RouteValues)
    {
        string resultURL=LinkExtensions.ActionLink(helper," ",ActionName,ControllerName, RouteValues, new object()).ToHtmlString();
        resultURL= resultURL.Replace("</a>","") .Replace("<a href=\"","") .Replace("\">","").Trim() ;

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Server.UrlDecode(resultURL));
    }
}
```

In the HTML I used it like this:

```
<span>Now you can paste this URL in your address bar : @(Html.ActionURLPath("CarregarFiltros", "Filtros", new { QueryId = "%0" , noCache = new Random().Next(0,1989)  }))</span>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Url.Action`, like so:

```
@Url.Action("Action", new { QueryName = ViewBag.QueryName })
```

or if you need the fully qualified URL:

```
@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { QueryName = ViewBag.QueryName }, "http")
```

Comment: Hey gram, thanks. But unfortunately this code triggers the specified action. I created a View to demonstrate what is the desired HTML output result and I'll edit the original question.

Comment: @ClayKaboom: This answer is correct.  Url.Action returns a url string of the matching action. See http://geekswithblogs.net/liammclennan/archive/2008/05/21/122298.aspx

Comment: @gram, It is indeed. I've tried it before but I was not attentive to the fact that I was using Html.Action instead of Url.Action. Thanks!